# pyspark : `SQLContext.read()` method returning a data frame on first call and NoneType for next calls : python

Tags: python, pyspark

```
def extract_data(self,sqlctx,query,number_of_partitions,url):
    try:
        df = sqlctx.read.format('jdbc') \
            .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
            .option("url", url) \
            .option("dbtable", "("+query+")as table_data") \
            .option("numPartitions",number_of_partitions) \
            .load()
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        print("EXCEPTION : "+str(e))
```

Above is the method I've written to extract some data from postgreSQL using pyspark in python (`sqlctx` is an object of `SQLContext`). On first call it is returning `df` as `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` object. but for later calls it is returning `df` as `NoneType` object. Can anybody please explain why is this happning ? Is there any error in code ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's probably because on subsequent calls an **exception** is being raised. You are just swallowing the exception. Does it not print that exception message?

Comment: Here is the exception message : `EXCEPTION : An error occurred while calling o46.load.
: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
  Position: 121
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2178)
 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
.....`

Comment: Does that answer your question then? You need to resolve the problems with other queries you're sending to the database. But swallowing exceptions without notifying the caller of failures is a problematic practice...

Comment: I got that @ErnestKiwele. The first query was fine but the next queries had some errors. Thanks !